# python: storing the results of a model in a file object

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

is it possible to store the algorithm that I ran in scikit learn in a physical file containing an object in my pc?

in R is possible to store a file containing the algorithm. Here I ran a random forest, but think about something simplier such as a regression

predicted_probs = clf.predict_proba(test[columns])

Comment: Not sure what you mean by storing and algorithm, but the closest you can get is storing the parameterization of the classifier? Alternatively you can pickle the classifier object itself: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: yes I meant storing the parameterization of the classifier!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `cPickle` you can store the object and then load it anywhere else again in Python. In R, I'm not entirely sure, never done that, but if you save the `working space` as worst alternative, it is going to be there.

[See tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loading_and_saving.html)